# Please blacklist the [technique] tag

Tags: support, status-completed

Even after we've finally managed to completely eradicate this awful, awful tag from the question pool, people still continue to add it to new questions.  Almost every day I see it reappear.  It just won't die.

Since moderators can't access the blacklist, I'm appealing to the developers; it may not technically be a meta-tag but it is far, far worse in its implications.  It's in the same category as the `[code]` tag on Stack Overflow or an `[english]` tag on ELU.  It describes almost *every* question on the site... in fact, it describes almost every question *on almost every site!*

I think this problem is persistent enough to warrant a genuine nuke-from-orbit.  Can we please add our first tag ever to the Seasoned Advice blacklist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok done -- added [technique](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique) to the tag blacklist.

Note that blacklist entries that don't get matches are automatically culled after about 6 months. So it is possible for it to recur unless it's actively matching.